# TOP records with sub top records sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I would require a query which can pull top 100 records, in which 50 has to be from a column named "Name" which has a value of "house" and in the same column another 50 records of value "plane".

Below is the sample table of it:

```
ID  Item_Code   Name    Source
1   987         House   PG
2   988         House   TES
3   989         Plane   ASD
4   990         House   WAL
5   991         Plane   PG
6   992         Plane   TES
```

Comment: What does "top 100 records" mean—the implication is that you want an ordering but you don't specify what by? (eg ID, Item_Code, Source, something else or do you just want 50 of each and don't care which 50?)

Comment: Have you use Oracle or SQL Server? Correct your tag if you use SQL server or remove accept from my answer if you use Oracle, because it won't work on Oracle.

Answer (score -7, accepted):

You can use this:

```
SELECT TOP 50 *
FROM sample_table
WHERE Name = 'House'
UNION ALL
SELECT TOP 50 *
FROM sample_table
WHERE Name = 'Plane'
```

Comment: `TOP` is not valid Oracle syntax

Comment: OK :) I missed tag `Oracle`. But what about downvotes vs accept :)

Answer (score 4):

You've tagged Oracle but accepted an answer using proprietary TSQL syntax that will not work in Oracle. Assuming that you are using Oracle as tagged then you can use

```
SELECT "ID",
       "Item_Code",
       "Name",
       "Source"
FROM   (SELECT YourTable.*,
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY "Name" ORDER BY "Item_Code") rn
        FROM   YourTable
        WHERE  "Name" IN ( 'House', 'Plane' ))
WHERE  rn <= 50;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a9bb3/1)

Comment: Or [this](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/74f7d/22) if the OP prefers to use `UNION ALL`

Comment: .. or if he is in a very very old Oracle version.

Comment: @ypercube you mean pre-1998? ;)